# how to output values from a list in ansible jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a variable that stores 2 values from task runs

```
- name: Set result
  set_fact:
    xresult: "{{ xresult | default([]) + [ yresult ] }}"
```

printed with debug it shows like this:

```
[u'abc', u'def']
```

I'm trying to display output in a jinja2 template like so:

```
{% for x in xresult %}
First run result: {{ x[0] }}
Second run result:{{ x[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output should look like this:

```
First run result: abc
Second run result: def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    xresult:
      - abc
      - def
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        output: |
          {% for i in range(0, xresult|count, 2) %}
          First run result: {{ xresult[i] }}
          Second run result: {{ xresult[i+1] }}
          {% endfor %}
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.split('\n') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
    "First run result: abc", 
    "Second run result: def", 
    ""
]
```

Comment: it works for the first result, but for the second it just outputs the second letter in the word, ex. 'e' instead of the whole value. if i put i+2 it outputs the third letter

Comment: The index of an array starts at 0. Why would anyone need i+2 to display an array "`that stores 2 values`"?

Comment: I dont need i+2, i only used it to show that the second result does not display properly for me for some reason, instead of the whole value, i+1 shows a single letter: 'e'  instead of 'def' being the value

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to update the question? The current code is not relevant anymore. Instead, you might want to post the code "`to show that the second result does not display properly for you for some reason`". Make it [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I had a typo in a variable somewhere, problem solved, this is the solution. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would essentially display the below value only.

```
First run result: a
Second run result: b
First run result: d
Second run result: e
```

Because you are using x[0] the value for the first iteration would be x=abc and you are using it as x[0] i.e x[abc] which effectively is a.

You need to limit the run and access the values directly so need to add some logic condition to achieve that.

Hope so the why is cleared just need to handle in the template.